# How do I change the colour of map borders in Google Chart API?

Tags: google-visualization

Is there a way that you can change the colour of the country borders in a map provided by Google Chart API?

As you can see, the borders stand out a bit too much for my liking.

[image]

Here's the URL if you wanted to play with it:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart
  ?cht=t
  &chs=440x220
  &chtm=world
  &chco=404F64,DDFFDD,006600
  &chf=bg,s,344152
  &chld=AEAUBECAFRILITJPMXMYNLNZSEUKUSZA
  &chd=s:BbENBKBBBBNCBDfC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this option is not available in the Google Chart API, as far as I know. You can always mention this feature request on the [Google Chart API Group list](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/topics)

Comment: Thanks Julien, that's what I thought... :(